# Running yasca tool from Runtime.getRunTime.exec() is taking more time than executing through command line

Tags: java, runtime, processbuilder

Code below shows How I am executing yasca through java. Process starts but it is taking longer time than command line execution, which takes less than a minute.Even I tried using ProcessBuilder but it is also taking more time as Runtime.getRunTime().exec

```
            String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c","cd \"F:\\Security Tools\\yasca\" && F: &&     yasca \"F:\\Security Tools\\HacmeBooks\" --output \"F:\\index\""};

            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: Problem got solved using

Comment: String line = "cmd.exe /c cd \"F:\\Security Tools\\yasca\" && F: && yasca \""+scriptName +"\"";
    CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    executor.setExitValue(1);
    try {
     int exitValue = executor.execute(commandLine);
    } catch (ExecuteException e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e1.printStackTrace();
    }